# Transform.left doesnt works Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this has been asked but can't figure out how to solve this.

```
if (this.gameObject.tag == "1Team"){
         
             unitGO.transform.position += transform.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
 
          } else if (this.gameObject.tag == "2Team"){
                           
             unitGO.transform.position += transform.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
 }
```

Unity marks in red transform.left ( Transform' does not contain a definition for 'left' ), so I dont know how to move my character to the left. I have tried using `-Transform.right`, `Transform.right * -movementSpeed`, `new Vector3( - 1,0,0)`, `unitGO.transform.position -= new Vector3(1,0,0) * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;` and other options without getting the movement I want.

if I change the tag from the GameObject I want to move, it actually moves right, so I dont think it's anything related to attaching scripts

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-left.html

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Also tried the exact same thing that appears as an example in the documentation

Comment: `If I chang the tag from the GameObject I want to move, it actually moves left` .. that sounds like your issue then ...  In general rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) instead of `==` to throw an error if there is a typo

Comment: Sorry, I meant Right, just changed that. Just tried using CompareTag but still not working. @derHugo

Comment: Could you describe `the movement I want.`?

Comment: Vector3 (-1,0,0). left direction on the X axis @derHugo

Answer (score 2):

While `Vector3.left` exists, for `Transform` there is only `transform.right`.

Which is no problem since for moving left you simply use `-transform.right`.

Now note that your intempts of using `new Vector3` also didn't work since if you use that you move in **global** space along Unity's X axis .. not in local space.

Now there are multiple possible solutions:

For moving in your local space do e.g.

```
if (gameObject.CompareTag("1Team"))
{
    unitGO.transform.position += transform.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
} 
else if (gameObject.CompareTag("2Team"))
{
    unitGO.transform.position -= transform.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Same as
    //unitGO.transform.position += -transform.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Or if you wan to move in Unity's global X axis then

```
if (gameObject.CompareTag("1Team"))
{
    unitGO.transform.position += Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
} 
else if (gameObject.CompareTag("2Team"))
{
    unitGO.transform.position += Vector3.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Same as
    //unitGO.transform.position -= Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Or if you actually rather wanted to move along the local X axis of the object you are moving you could rather use `Translate` which by default uses the local space of the moved object

```
if (gameObject.CompareTag("1Team"))
{
    unitGO.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
} 
else if (gameObject.CompareTag("2Team"))
{
    unitGO.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Same as
    //unitGO.transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

---

In general rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) instead of `==` to throw an error if there is a typo

Comment: yup, already tried that but still not moving:(. thank you for your time tho

Comment: Please define `not working` .. what is happening instead?

Comment: Solved!! the problem was with the Tag "2Team". I also tried copying the Tag to make sure there was no spell error. Can't undertand why, but now I changed the name of the tag and it moves.